# How to Calculate DATEDIF formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the `CalculatedValue` for the formula `=DATEDIF("5/7/2018","6/6/2018","m")`.In `Excel` it returns zero.

I would like to know what process used while calculating the above formula.

Can anyone please let me know *the actual process behind getting the month between two dates* ?

Answer (score 2):

"5/7/2018" is May 7th, but there is not a full month until June 6th, hence the zero result.
`DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,"M")` gives the number of **complete months** in the period.

Please also note that dates in Excel can be tricky, as it depends on your regional settings.
"5/7/2018" could be July 5th (in my region), hence after June 6th, which should give a #NUM error if you use the `DATEDIF` function.

Comment: Do you have any further questions regarding my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("5/7/2018"),DATEVALUE("6/6/2018"),"m")
```

will return **0**

[image]

However:

```
=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("5/7/2018"),DATEVALUE("6/7/2018"),"m")
```

will return **1**